# How to create a table and import/insert the entire contents of csv into that table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a script that imports the csv data into a table using a cron job.

Is it possible to create a table and insert all of the csv contents into it without having to set the field names like I do in my code below.

```
<?php

include_once '/db-connection.php';

$csvFilePath = "stock_sold.csv";
$file = fopen($csvFilePath, "r");
fgets($file);
while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `stock_sold` 
                (`sku`, `stock_sold`, `id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sdi", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Something along the lines of the code below, where I do not have to set/name the table name, it could use the filename for example and where it imports all the columns and data into the table.

The reason I was after this approach compared the the code above is that I do not have to adjust my code each time to account for the extra columns added onto the csv. The script runs and imports the data regardless if new fields are added they are automatically imported into the table aswell.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CREATE TABLE `filename.csv`()");
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `filename.csv`()");
$stmt->execute();
```

csv could import like this

| sku | stock-sold | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 1 |
| a2 | 10 | 2 |
| a3 | 5 | 3 |
| a4 | 4 | 4 |

or like this without me having to add the column `colour` to the prepared statement. It just imports all of the columns/data after every import.

| sku | stock-sold | id | colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 1 | red |
| a2 | 10 | 2 | blue |
| a3 | 5 | 3 | black |
| a4 | 4 | 4 | purple |

I do not have SUPER privileges on mysql as I am on a shared hosting server.  `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` or `LOAD DATA INFILE` are not an option for me.

Comment: If the field names and CSV titles are the same, use the titles ad field name for your tablet. If you provide a CSV example and Tablet structure it will help to find best answer.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "_without having to set the field names_"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` like this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$csvPath'
INTO TABLE $table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(sku, stock-sold, colour)
```